# Access : DSUM acting weird

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to calculate a running sum with an access 2010 query and the DSUM function
datas are:
table cumulvsce_2
COquille / Date  /1ere apparition
0   /   07/03/2018   / 1    
0   /   16/03/2018   / 1    
0   /   19/03/2018   / 1    
0   /   22/03/2018  / 1
0   /   28/03/2018  / 0 
0   /   29/03/2018  / 1
0   /   30/03/2018  / 0
0   /   31/03/2018  / 0

the goal is to calculate the running sum of "1ere application" for each date

Query is:

```
  SELECT CumulVSCE_2.COQUILLE, CumulVSCE_2.Date, CumulVSCE_2.[1ere apparition], DSum([cumulvsce_2]![1ere apparition],"CumulVSCE_2","[date]<=" & [date]) AS Expr1 INTO CumulVSCE_3b
    FROM CumulVSCE_2
    GROUP BY CumulVSCE_2.COQUILLE, CumulVSCE_2.Date, CumulVSCE_2.[1ere apparition];
```

Results is:
COQUILLE    / Date  / 1ere apparition / Expr1
0   / 07/03/2018    /1  /1
0   /16/03/2018 /1  /2
0   /19/03/2018 /1  /3
0   /22/03/2018 /1  /4
0   /28/03/2018 /0  /0
0   /29/03/2018 /1  /6
0   /30/03/2018 /0  /0
0   /31/03/2018 /0  /0

which is weird because value for 28/10/2018 should be 4 (1+1+1+1+0) and value for 39, 30 and 31/3  should be 5 (1+1+1+1+0+1; 1+1+1+1+0+1+0;1+1+1+1+0+1;+0+0)

Any idea what is wrong with the formulae ?

```
DSum([cumulvsce_2]![1ere apparition],"CumulVSCE_2","[date]<=" & [date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with proper and forced formatting of the date values:

```
DSum("[1ere apparition]","CumulVSCE_2","[date] <= #" & Format([date], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```